# How to check whether database is consistent or not?

Tags: database, relational-database, integrity

I want to know how to check whether a given database is consistent or not? As in some environment with high update rates,it may be expensive to check constriants. So database may get inconsistent with respect to unenforced constraints.

Comment: Check IF it is inconsistent, or fix it? In the former case you could take a snapshot and run queries on that to look for inconsistencies. In the latter, you are better off shutting it down once a day or once a week, and running some fixup procedure on it.

Answer (score 0):

The constraints are the way you have to tell the Database when it is considered as consistent. If the DB is lacking such rules, the consistency can only be checked with user querys and can be only enforced through the "good use" of SQL statements (or other menas like triggers and stored procedures that would be more expensive than constraints themselves)

The only workaround I can think of if you don't want to enforce integrity or consistency with constraints, is having such constraints defined but disabled and at some point (at night, or whenever you have a low workload and want to), try to enable them and see what happens. The DB will complain if the data dosen't meet the requeriments of constraints.